# Как в std::unordered_multimap реализуется хранение пар с одинаковыми ключами?

Tags: c++

Я реализую аналог **std::unordered_multimap**, делаю это на **C**.

Меня интересует, каким образом в **std::unordered_multimap** (да и вообще) реализуется хранение пар с одинаковыми ключами? Я покопался в исходниках, но шаблоны, умноженные на инопланетные идентификаторы, исключают даже малейший шанс понять того, что там происходит внутри.

Проблемы такие:

1) Если хэширование происходит только по ключу, тогда пары с одинаковыми ключами будут выстраиваться в цепочки, **длина которых не зависит от количества ячеек таблицы**.

И это очень плохо.

2) Если хэширование происходит и по ключу, и по значению, тогда значения пар, уже находящихся в таблице, нельзя будет изменять прямо на месте. Сперва их нужно будет вырезать, затем изменять и потом вновь вставлять.

Подскажите, как в хэш-мультиотображениях принято решать описанную проблему.

Comment: Почему вы считаете, что это "очень плохо" - не ясно.

Comment: Волшебных структур данных не существует, всегда приходится чем-то жертвовать. В хеш таблицах это список коллизий, от которого никуда не уйти в общем случае.

Comment: А вообще, почитайте про open hashing и closed hashing, вместо просмотра исходников.

Comment: ixSci, про методы хеширования я хорошо знаю. Меня интересует, как устроен конкретно std::unordered_multimap

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Хеширование, разумеется, производятся только по ключу. И да, в традиционной реализации, пары с одинаковыми ключами будут выстраиваться в цепочку в одном bucket хэш-таблицы.

Средства итерирования по `std::unordered_multimap` гарантируют, что пары с одинаковым ключом будут идти непрерывной последовательностью в процессе итерирования. Поэтому как ни верти, разумная реализация будет вынуждена хранить их рядом.

Ни о каком хэшировании "и по ключу, и по значению" в `std::unordered_multimap` не может быть и речи.

Comment: Я полагал, что хэширование и по ключу, и по значению, даст преимущества - полноценное размазывание пар по всем ячейкам (слотам) таблицы... Но в этом случае поиск так же будет возможен только для конкретной пары, поиск же по одному лишь ключу станет невозможен... Спасибо, разобрался.